# Free ready-made models for study? (e.g. for rooting hair)

Tags: hair

I want to try modeling hair, and generally understand how to use the bezier/taper curves method, but I have trouble figuring out how to root it believably to the head. I think I'd be able to learn better if I could find a model with well-rooted and separable strands to study off of. Is there a repository for such free "for study" models anywhere? Otherwise, how best to go about rooting hair? Thanks!

(PS I believe this sculptor used some sort of planes method to model the hair [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qB6FOVMp9LY); is that indeed what the technique is called so I can look up tutorials?)

Comment: The [resources](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/15360/599) post here has many links that should help you find what you need...

Comment: About your PS: These planes are called **hair cards**. You can use the hair particle system to lay them out. Have a look here: https://www.blender.org/user-stories/using-blender-in-game-development-by-embark/. At the bottom there is the full video linked.